# CSS Responsive image "shows up fully" on-screen no-stretch background with precise text placement

Tags: css

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="fullscreen"> 
  
    <div class="textbox">Testing</div>
    
  </div>
</div>
```

[image]

I'm trying to have an image fully show up based on the size of a screen, and to have text ("Testing" in the textbox class) show up in a precise designated area in the image, as shown above.

Trying to get the above to work with this [codepen](https://codepen.io/yosunchang/pen/eYNzZPx?editors=1111), but I am defeated to admit that after an hour of fiddling with css, I am nowhere close.

It is pretty frustrating that css doesn't seem to work as expected, where the image doesn't seem to want to nest to full height etc.

Answer (score 1):

I would like to suggest if you add image using img HTML tag you have better control on image in relation with "Testing" text. Please check below my snippet. You can adjust position of "Testing" by "top" position on ".textbox" class :

```css
.container{
        min-height: 100%;
        margin: 0;  
        padding: 0;
      }
      .fullscreen{
        width: auto;
        height: 100%;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
        position:relative;
      }

      .textbox{
        position:absolute;
        top:55%;
        left: 50%;
        -webkit-transform: translateX(-50%);
        transform: translateX(-50%);
        z-index:3;
        text-align:center;
      }
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="fullscreen"> 
    <img src="http://print.drawmaticar.com/preview.jpg"   style="width:100%;"/>
  
    <div class="textbox">Testing</div>
    
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This is almost it, but I am trying to have the image adjust so that it shows itself entirely on any device size. (Not just responsive width, but having the entire image scale to the max size of the screen.)

Comment: ok but I believe it is working full scale of max width of device as I have checked in all break-points. Please check. 

If you have still challenge anywhere please let me know.

Comment: i mean to say that it should stretch to show entirely based on device size...  currently, it cuts off https://gyazo.com/b94274ffa537fa844a04e2f60867ed6c

Comment: Sorry but I am still little bit confuse. As per my snippet it is fully responsive in all breakpoints that's mean image will adjust width wise (full width) to the total width of device. Height will automatically update in the proportion of width which lead to scroll in small height devices. In small devices you will get scroll to view below part, it obvious.

Now, if you are looking to also update image to height then it is a new case. In this scenario you have to change entire code in such a way so that after rendering you will get a single image with text.

Comment: I mean to say with no scrolling required

Comment: just web browser. suppose a user views it using a small phone screen, the entire image should show without scrolling

Comment: Ohk, it is tricky now. Need to find if there is any front end tool or library or method which convert image  and text together. By current approach I am not sure you will get the desired result. I will check if I can find something for you.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
background: url('path/to/img.jpg') no-repeat center center / cover;
```

Answer (score 0):

Normally, if you call the image in background means need to add the padding-bottom in percentage.. It means the image height/width*100

**css**

```
.fullscreen {
 padding-bottom: 129.411%;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

[`Backgorund Image`](https://codepen.io/creativesingh/pen/WNvxwqy)

you have to make `background-size:cover` instead of `100%` and make `height:100vh` to make it visible.